# What is wrong in this code to use camera in android studio?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

I copied the following code from :
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

I also added the permission in the manifest file. But the app is crashing as soon as it starts. What is wrong here?

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
ImageView  mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);


    //
    View.OnClickListener imgButtonClickListener=new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    };
    //

    b1.setOnClickListener(imgButtonClickListener);

}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent()
{
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}

}
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.nirvan.cameraexample.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="177dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="IMG"
    android:id="@+id/imgButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting in your log?

Comment: If it crashes, there will be an exception what is it? Always include error messages and exceptions in the question.

Comment: There are votes to close this question. Please edit the question and provide more data about the exception you're getting and explain how you compiled the code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
ImageView mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

should be inside of your `onCreate()` after your setContentView

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ImageView mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

That line is assigning to `mImageView` the results of `findViewById(R.id.img)` which needs to run after you've inflated your layout in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Comment: If you add whole line ImageView mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img); in oncreate() then mImageView will not accessible in onResultActivity().

Answer (score 1):

Just replace line

> ImageView mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

with

> ImageView mImageView;

and in `onCreate()` add below line

> mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);